# Google Custom Search Engine Autocomplete Not Working

Tags: google-custom-search

I've integrated Google Custom Search Engine to a website. Everything works perfectly except Autocomplete feature. Autocomplete is set to 'ON' in control panel. Going through the network response from my Chrome browser I can see the response is returned as a blank array. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: ever found a solution?

Answer (score -1):

I just found out that google has stopped autocomplete api as per this blog post.
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ca/2015/07/update-on-autocomplete-api.html

Comment: They stopped the standalone autocomplete API, but autocomplete is still a part of Google Custom Search.